# PHP MySQL query - Show row only once

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a table similar to this

```
id    message    state        timestamp
1     abcd       Heartbeat    1970-01-01 01:00
2     efgh       Start        1970-01-01 02:00
3     sdcvsd     Stop         1970-01-01 02:30
4     efgh       Start        1970-01-01 03:00
5     sdcvsd     Stop         1970-01-01 03:30
6     dsdfsd     Heartbeat    1970-01-01 04:10
7     sdcsc      Heartbeat    1970-01-01 04:20
8     sewwdf     Heartbeat    1970-01-01 04:30
```

What I would like to do is query this table in PHP and show the rows, but only show the latest row of Heartbeat, because it is very repetitive and I only need to know when the last one happened. All other states will echo even if they are repetitive. So the output would be (newest at the top):

```
8 sewwdf     Heartbeat    1970-01-01 04:30
5 sdcvsd     Stop         1970-01-01 03:30
4 efgh       Start        1970-01-01 03:00
3 sdcvsd     Stop         1970-01-01 02:30
2 efgh       Start        1970-01-01 02:00
```

I have only been able to leave it out with

```
mysqli_query($con, " SELECT * FROM msg WHERE state <> 'Heartbeat' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 16 " );
```

I don't think I can use `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT` for more than one state.

How can I query only the latest Heartbeat state without effecting other states or remove the older ones in the PHP echo?

Comment: `mysqli_query($con, " SELECT * FROM msg GROUP BY id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 16" );` try this

Comment: Also `1970-01-01 01:00` ? I think some problem is there?

Comment: I made the date/time up for the example.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM msg GROUP BY(state) HAVING timestamp = MAX(timestamp) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 16`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This also works:

```
select * from
`msg`
where
`state` = 'Heartbeat'
and
`id` =  
(
select
`id`
from
`msg`
where
`state` = 'Heartbeat'
order by `timestamp` desc
limit 1
)

union

select * from
`msg`
where
`state` <> 'Heartbeat'

order by `timestamp` desc
```

Comment: These id's are real, do u want to enumerate result rows ?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM msg WHERE message = '$foo' AND state <> 'Heartbeat' UNION SELECT * FROM msg WHERE state = 'Heartbeat' AND id = (SELECT id FROM msg WHERE state = 'Heartbeat' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 16`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM msg GROUP BY(state) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 16" );
```

Comment: This shows one row of every state. I need all states ungrouped, except 'Heartbeat' state, which I need the latest to be shown.

Comment: No, this groups each state. I do not want that. Please read the question carefully and see example.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**Your query is:**

```
mysqli_query($con, " SELECT * FROM msg WHERE state <> 'Heartbeat' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 16 " );
```

**I think It should be :**

```
mysqli_query($con, " SELECT * FROM msg WHERE state="Heartbeat" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 16 " );
```

You can see my attached picture, What happen in their? Thank You.

Comment: No, this only outputs the one state.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Query :

```
SELECT * FROM `msg` GROUP BY `state` ORDER BY `id` DESC,`Timestamp` DESC LIMIT 16
```

it will work

Comment: No, this groups each state. I do not want that.

Comment: so you just want `state with heartbeat` ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this also

```
select * from `test2` where `state` != 'Heartbeat' OR `id` = (select `id` from `test2` where `state` = 'Heartbeat' order by `date` desc limit 1 )
```

if need order with date

```
select * from `test2` where `state` != 'Heartbeat' OR `id` = (select `id` from `test2` where `state` = 'Heartbeat' order by `date` desc limit 1 ) ORDER BY date DESC
```